# A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution Room

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

Пожалуйста, помогите. Я использую room. Но у меня есть такая ошибка. Если вы удалите эту часть кода

> @Database( entities = [Current::class], version = 1 )

Но мне определенно нужно, чтобы это было в моем коде, иначе все будет неправильно.

Это Forecast Database.kt

```
package com.ggenius.whattowearkotlin.data.db

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.ggenius.whattowearkotlin.data.db.entity.Current

@Database(
    entities = [Current::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class ForecastDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun currentWeatherDao(): CurrentWeatherDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: ForecastDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                ForecastDatabase::class.java, "forecast.db")
                .build()
    }
}
```

Это мой grade смотрите под комментарием room я думаю тут ошибка.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ggenius.whattowearkotlin"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'

    // Navigation
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$navigation_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$navigation_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3"

    // Room
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"

    // Kotlin Android Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // Kodein
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:$kodein_version"
    implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:$kodein_version"

    // Better dateTime-time support even on older Android versions
    implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0"

    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // Groupie RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.7.0'

    // Preference
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1"

    // WeatherLocation
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1"

    // New Material Design
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0"

    //test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Вот скрин ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: На скрине у вас есть синее предложение запустить сборку с выводом большего кол-ва логов. Нажмите на это. И приведите текстом какой лог ошибки вам выдаст сборка при этом

Comment: Как-то зависимостей маловато: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#setup насколько я понимаю всё что не помечено в комментариях как "optional" - обязательно. Ну и не стоит использовать беты, если вы не активный тестер или в ней нет нового, необходимого вам, функционала и вы не планируете релиз к тому времени как его допилят. К тому же бета старая - уже есть релиз 2.4.1

Comment: `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"` - и вот тут не понятно, переменная `room_version` где-то объявлена? И совпадает ли её значение с версией здесь: `androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-beta01`